# Delphi wrong architecture on libdbunwind.1.0.dylib

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

In just one MacBook Air machine running Mac OS X 10.8.2 I get the following error:

???.app/Contents/MacOS//libdbunwind.1.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

On another two MacBookAirs it works nicely.

Checked with lipo of course the architecture is i386. All the dylibs are deployed by Delphi 10.1 Upd 2

I'm completely lost with this error. Any feedback will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Regards,

Comment: I don't think Delphi is supporting OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Embarcadero documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites) Delphi supports OS X 10.9 Mavericks and newer but not OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion.

So I'm afraid you or your clients would have to update their OS to newer version for your program to work on it.

Comment: Thank you very much! It has been a great help.